# Grouping data on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rank

I have this table in SQL Server:

```
Year    Month       Quantity
----------------------------
2015    January     10
2015    February    20
2015    March       30
2014    November    40
2014    August      50
```

How can I identify the different years and months adding two more columns that group the same years with a number and then different months in sequential way like the example

```
Year    Month       Quantity    Group   Subgroup
------------------------------------------------
2015    January     10          1       1
2015    February    20          1       2
2015    March       30          1       3
2014    November    40          2       1
2014    August      50          2       2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) to calculate the groups for you:

```
SELECT t1.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Year DESC) AS [Group],
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY DATEPART(month, Month + ' 01 2010')) AS [SubGroup]
FROM t1
ORDER BY 4, 5
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/113d1/9).

Answer (score 0):

To associate group and subgroup with a number you can do this:

```
WITH RankedTable AS (
  SELECT year, month, quantity,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by year order by Month) AS rn
  FROM yourtable)
SELECT year, month, quantity,
   SUM (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR) as year_group, 
   rn AS subgroup
FROM RankedTable
```

Here `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` clause calculates rank of a month within a `year`.
And `SUM() ... OVER` calculates running SUM for the months with rank 1.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/113d1/18)

Comment: it should work on SQL 2008? what if I have a third column to group? it it will not work right?

Comment: it does not work for me, I get Incorrect syntax near 'order' on the line you specify the SUM

Comment: is there any other way to do it without the sum?

Comment: @amit's answer does not have sum

Comment: no problem, I use this DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Myyear) AS [year_group] and is working, thanks!

Comment: @Bulat, Support for SUM() OVER() was added in SQL Server 2012, as far as I know.

Comment: OVER() - Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse Public Preview.